# Add handler in runtime within a constructor VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

**REEDIT**

I have reedited the question to be more understandable following the advices of @enigmativity in his comments.

This is an example of what I want to do in my program. I tried to make it as simple as I can, so I hope you can understand my question.

The problem is the following: I am trying to add handlers dynamically, because I have an object which needs to fire a handler when something happens on it, and I can create this objects dynamically in the program. Maybe following this example you could understand my problem.

If I have an object, for example, a car, with its own properties (doors, wheels, motor..), and something happen in the road, I want the handler BREAK fires, and in the BREAK function do whatever I need to make it break. Here is the example code of the class for this object:

```
Public Class Car

Public Property carName As String
Public Property wheels As Integer
Public Property motor As String
Public Property color As String
Public Property speed As Decimal
Private Event BreakCar()

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal name_ As String, ByVal wheels_ As Integer, motor As String, color As String, ByVal speed As Decimal)
    carName = name_
    wheels = wheels_
    motor = motor_
    color = color_
    speed = speed_
End Sub

Public Sub Break()
    Try
        AddHandler BreakCar, AddressOf EmergencyBreak
        RaiseEvent AutoMsg()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message & ". Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub EmergencyBreak()
    Try

        MsgBox("Emergency Break")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message & ". Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Also, in the main form I have something like this:

```
Public Class frmMain
...

Private Sub AddMe(ByVal name_ As String, ByVal wheels_ As Integer, ByVal motor_ As String, ByVal color_ As String, ByVal speed_ As Decimal, Byval initCoordinates_ as PointLatLng)

    Try

        unitsList.Add(New Car(name_, wheels_, motor_, color_, speed_))

        Dim marker As GMapMarker
        marker = New GMarkerGoogle(initCoordinates_, GMarkerGoogleType.orange_dot)
        marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always
        marker.ToolTipText = name_
        meOverlay.Markers.Add(marker)

        Dim lvItem As ListViewItem
        lvItem = lvUnits.Items.Add(name_)
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(initCoordinates_.Lat, 4))
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(initCoordinates_.Lng, 4))

        Dim unit_ As Car = unitsList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.carName = name_)
        unit_.Break()

        Dim tTemp_ As Thread = New Thread(Sub() CarMovement(unit_))
        tTemp_.Name = name_
        tTemp_.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
        tTemp_.Start()
        unitsThreadList.Add(tTemp_)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message & ". Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

End Sub
...
End Class
```

With this, I am trying to add cars in the system, using a different thread to each one, and after adding the car to the system, start its handler to make it BREAK when some condition happens.

My problem is that the handler never fires, and I don't know the reasons because when something happens to the car X, the handler Break() must fires but it doesn't.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe it is not possible to add handlers to each object created dynamically like this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make your life easier and get rid of the `Catch ex As Exception` lines in your code. Never ever write them in again. It's a bad anti-pattern. You should only ever catch **specific** exceptions that you can **meaningfully** handle.

Comment: Now, where is the code that you use to create the N `Bot`s?

Comment: Thank for your advice @Enigmativity! Now I am just printing the error in the catch just for debugging. I edit the question to show you where I create this N bots!

Comment: Debugging is generally far easier with the available debugging tools. Don't use `catch` like that. It's just too easy to leave it in for production code.

Comment: Your code is confusing. Can you please make it as simple as possible for me to copy, paste and run?

Comment: Yes @Enigmativity, you're right! I usually use log4net for debugging, but you're write about forget to erase all this catch from the code!

Comment: Yes! I will try.. Let me edit it

Comment: @Enigmativity maybe it could be easier if I send you the code, what do you think? Because the object ´messageDispatcher comes from an external library, and I think it could be difficult to run this application without this library.. Also to run it maybe you need another computer which asks to this program for its position.. It is hard to simplify it for me. Maybe you have or know about some sample code which runs an event called from an object created dinamically?

Comment: You need to make a [mcve] that shows your problem. It's up to you to get the code into a state to show us. Then tell us what's going wrong. We can then fix it.

Comment: Just to be clear you mean "Brake", not "Break"? As in you use the "brake" to slow down a car?

Comment: Your code is still far from a [mcve]. I should be able to copy, paste, and run with a minimal amount of setting things up. Right now heaps of your code is missing - there's no `CarMovement` method, for example. And `AutoMsg`.

Comment: It's really not standard for a class to handle its own methods. So the `AddHandler BreakCar, AddressOf EmergencyBreak` in `Break` is weird. You're adding a handler in the method that seems like it might be trying to raise the event - if that's the case there's no need for an event or a handler - you'd just call the code directly.

Comment: The main problem here is that in my original application, I am not using a few cars, I am using a few bots, and each bot is listening in a different port. This bot is moving throught the map, and when the emisor ask for the position, the specific bot gives a response with its position. The package of the emisor does not allow to me to access to the specific port of the bot which the emisor wants to communicate, it is transparent for me. I have made a single bot, and when I open X bots (X programs), and each bot listen in a different port, the handler of each bot fires when needed

Comment: Now what I am trying to do is just to have a single program to manage X bots at the same time. With this program I don't need to open X programs for X bots. In this program, I set a different port to each bot, but when I receive the package of the emisor, as I cannot see the port, I cannot redirect the package to the specific bot. This is the reason why I cannot have a single method in the main form for all the bots. And what I want to achieve is to have, in my bot class, the function which manage the request. With this, I can say in the creation of the bot the instruction Listen.Start()

Comment: And when a request is received, if I have X bots running in the application, each one in a different port, the request goes directly to the specific bot which is listening for that port.. I hope you can understand what I am trying to do.. I know it is a little bit difficult to understand.. and thank you very much for your patience =)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. This is why people should ask concrete question - talk about bots in your question and not cars - and why you need to provide a [mcve]. Please show me your working code for bots (at the end of your current question; don't rewrite). Show everything necessary and show where the problem is in the code. Then I can help. I need code that I can run and see the problem you're facing.